# Selenium and Java trying to find a <select> tag inside a table cell <td>

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using all the standard ways to parse a table.

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.name("TableName"));
List<WebElement> tableRows = table.findElements(By.xpath("tbody/tr"));

for(WebElement trElement : tableRows ) {  
List<WebElement> td_collection = trElement.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

WebElement dropDownElement = null;

for (WebElement tdElement : td_collection)
```

There is a select tag within the columns:

```
<tr role="row">
   <td>
      <select name="ABC">
         <option value="1">name 1</option>
         <option value="2">name 2</option>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td>some name</td>
</tr>
```

I tried:

```
dropDownElement = (WebElement) tdElement.findElements(By.tagName("select"));
dropDownElement = tdElement
```

I can't find the `SELECT` tag within the table.  The select name is unique but there is no guarantee it will be in the table.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on issue which you are facing. The questions doesn't seems to be clear.

Comment: what is your trElement? you did not use tableRows element in your code after you found it.

Comment: Your HTML does not provide a good overview either, where is your "TableName" attribute?

Comment: Please take a minute to review the code you posted. I think in the process of posting it you lost some of the relevant bits. Right now it seems incomplete.

Comment: Also, your HTML was not valid. Close tags are `</td>` not `<\td>`... fixed that.

Comment: Fixed the <\td> sorry if that was confusion....

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to parse the HTML table to get the `SELECT` since it has a `name` attribute. Use this code

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[name='ABC']")));
```

Then once you have `select` you can choose an `OPTION`, etc.

Comment: the select name is not guarantee to be in the table.

Comment: Then you can use the first line... it's not dependent on the `SELECT` being in the `TABLE`.

Comment: Updated my answer to be more clear based on your new comment.

Comment: JeffC, not sure what you mean by saying "use the first line"

Comment: The first code line. I removed the other since it's not needed.

Comment: JeffC, the problem is not walking thru the table rows or columns,  When I get to the Column <td> it has an inner tag <select>  I'm trying this solution:  tdElement.findElements(By.xpath("/select")); but that does not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117024/discussion-between-gringo-golf-and-jeffc).

Comment: Did you try the code in my answer? Did it not work or what error did it throw?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS selector to get it:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("tr td select")
```

Answer (score 0):

Team,

Two items i was doing wrong.

1) I was taking the cell WebElement and saying findElements..... instead of findElement.

2) was using By.xpath I changed that to be By.tagName...

So the line of code to change is:

```
dropDownElement = tdElement.findElement(By.tagName("select"));
```

Comment: By not being any more specific than tagname, if the page gets updated and the `SELECT` you want is no longer the first one, the script will break.